# Create gridview with 2 rows in header

Tags: asp.net, gridview, footer

I want to create gridview with 2 rows in head, something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do merging in the gidview header following is article linki that will help you to achieve same thing

[GridView column header merging in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/448762/GridView-column-header-merging-in-ASP-NET)

[Merge Header - GridView/DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16049/Merge-Header-GridView-DataGrid)

Answer (score 0):

Use colspan:

```
<td colspan="2">1</td>
```

Comment: The answer would depend on if the grid is created at runtime or design time.

Comment: in gridview I can not insert html code, this row is for design